# Selenium C# Code Works But Need Waits or Delays

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

By adding a while(ele == null) loop, I got the code to run and work most of the time out of the debugger. Pretty ugly. This leads me to think that I need to over ride the FindElements() function using a wrapper but have no idea how to do this to add some delay. There is an example at [Explicit Wait for findElements in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397608/explicit-wait-for-findelements-in-selenium-webdriver) but it's written in JavaScript. I put that example in the code below. Can some one guide me on this?

```
        public void WriteAPost()
        {
           ele = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7.ltmttdrg.g0qnabr5.ojkyduve")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Create Post");

            while(ele == null)
            {
                ele = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7.ltmttdrg.g0qnabr5.ojkyduve")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Create Post");
            }

            ele.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            ele = driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();

            PClipboard.SetText("Post text to use for Text Area");
            ele.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + 'v');

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            ele = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@role = 'button']")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Post");

            while (ele == null)
            {
                ele = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@role = 'button']")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Post");
            }

            ele.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            driver.Quit();
     }

    static class PClipboard
    {
        public static void SetText(string p_Text)
        {
            Thread STAThread = new Thread(
                delegate ()
                {
                    // Use a fully qualified name for Clipboard otherwise it
                    // will end up calling itself.
                    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(p_Text);
                });
            STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            STAThread.Start();
            STAThread.Join();
        }
    }
}

// Javascript FindElements() wrapper

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows you to execute the FindElements call but specify your own timeout explicitly for this single lookup
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If you want no timeout, you can pass in TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) to return an empty list if no elements match immediately. But then you may as well use the original method
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="driver">The IWebDriver instance to do the lookup with</param>
    /// <param name="findBy">The By expression to use to find matching elements</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">A timespan specifying how long to wait for the element to be available</param>
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this IWebDriver driver, By findBy, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        return wait.Until((d) =>
        {
            var elements = d.FindElements(findBy);
            return (elements.Count > 0)
                ? elements
                : null;
        });
    }
```

Comment: _...I don't get the correct results..._ Where are you exactly stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for a condition to be met:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(id))));
```

or you can wait implicitly:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeInSeconds);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just don't know where in the code to wait. I debug the code line by line and all elements are found. But running the code without debugging doesn't work

Comment: Try using driver wait after every action that requires navigation or scripts to run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't know where in the code to wait.

Personally, my Selenium code is full of "test failure reporting" tests and try-catch blocks which report where the failure happened. If you model your code this way, it should narrow down the problem and clue you to where waits are needed.

Comment: I revised my code above to do a little at a time and found consistant failure. It has something to do with breaking on the FindElements() call. Please read my problem description. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: It's definitely the FindElements() call, I replaced the code above with `ele = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7.ltmttdrg.g0qnabr5.ojkyduve")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Create Post"); ele.Click();` that replaces having to use a foreach loop and when I break on the FindElements() code, press Step Over(F10), then Continue the text area gets set to the text. If I remove the break point ele is null. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I just updated my problem description and code snippets. Please see new description and code snipperts. Basically, I think I need to create a wrapper for Selenium FindElements() method.